# Creating a DialogFragment with FrameLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been asked to do this and I have no idea how these work, I tried reading documentation but it doesn't really fit this specific need?

My Activity receives a notification, parses the $title and $message and inflates this DialogFragment with this info.

I created the relevant XML file and loaded it into this pre-defined `FullScreenMessageView: FrameLayout`

```
class FullScreenMessageView: FrameLayout, View.OnTouchListener {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { this.init(context) }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) { this.init(context) }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { this.init(context) }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.full_screen_notification_loader, this)
        setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    fun setTitle(title: String) {
        //TODO: Adding title to XML view
    }

    fun setMessage(message: String){
        //TODO: Adding message to XML view
    }
}
```

I also have this DialogFragment with a lot of boiletplate code:

```
class FullScreenLoaderDialog: DialogFragment()  {
    private lateinit var message: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        message = arguments!!.getString(MESSAGE_PARAM, DEFAULT_LOADING_MESSAGE)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return FullScreenLoader(this.context!!)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        this.dialog!!.window.apply {
            requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            val width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            setLayout(width, height)
        }
        (this.view as FullScreenLoader).setLoadingText(message)
        this.view!!.setOnClickListener { this.dismiss() }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        return Dialog(activity!!, R.style.AppTheme_LoadingDialog)
    }


    companion object{
        private const val DEFAULT_LOADING_MESSAGE = "Loading"
        private const val MESSAGE_PARAM="MESSAGE_PARAM"
        fun newInstance(message: String) = FullScreenLoaderDialog().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(MESSAGE_PARAM, message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to inflate this fragment from my activity but not sure how to connect this custom view into the DialogFragment. And I'm also not sure how to add the title to the XML view or where to call these setTitle and setMessage functions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use the [navigation component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfEOYxWVRTM&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9VpBMZUS9geQtc5RJ2RsUd&index=3)

Comment: if you want to create a alert dialog or a inflate a custom view check this library - https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/main/documentation/CORE.md#custom-views